# redirect nested folder (sub sub folder) to own index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cpanel

How to redirect from `example.com/projects/login` to `example.com/projects/login/index.php`?

**My .htaccess:**

```
#Force www:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

#Removing .PHP Extension
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Set XSS Protection header
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't require any rewrite rule. Just use `DirectoryIndex` directive at top of your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on

#Force www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

#Removing .PHP Extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Set XSS Protection header
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I'm using shared host cpanel and htaccess  file is in root and `example.com/projects/login/index.php` link is ok

Comment: with / at the end of each link, I get 404 too.

Comment: yes projects is a new folder and login is a php login system and inside of login folder I have may php files like index, profile, rest password and...

Comment: I placed inside of login folder and that redirected from `http://www.example.com/projects/login` to `http://www.example.com/projects/login/` added a / at the end of link

Comment: No, Just these two links `example.com/projects/login/index.php` and `example.com/projects/login/index`  works fine and this link get 404 too `http://www.seointro.ir/projects/login/index/`

Comment: I find it, after removing `Removing .PHP Extension` lines, that solved, Should I Remove those line? But I can't remove, there is a confilict, How Can I solve that?

Comment: Thanks, what was my problem?

Comment: Adding `.php` without checking existence of that `.php` file was the issue. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f` does that check.